# one of the two background threads stop randomly without any notice(In Logs)

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a Windows Service where in it has two threads which should be running indefinetly(while(true)) and both have same sleep times (this happens under while())
When the service is started both threads start and work for certain point of time and after that the second thread stops leaving no trace behind in logs. Exception Handling is done at all levels.

I have managed to resolve this issue by having different sleep time  for each thread, which I do not think is a best Idea. Here is how I Initialize thread ..

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
Associate = new Thread(new AssociateProc().Associator) { IsBackground = true, Name = "Associator" };
Associate.Start();
DISAssociate = new Thread(new AssociateProc().DisAssociator) { IsBackground = true, Name = "DISAssociator" };
DISAssociate.Start();
     }
```

ASSOCIATE & DISASSOCIATE METHOD DEF IS

```
public void Associator()
{
  while (true)
  {
    try
    {
      //METHODS CALLED
    }
    catch(exception ex)
    {
       //Exception Handling
    }
    thread.sleep()
  }

}
```

Please let me know for better implementations.

While trying to find out the pattern where in the scenario repeats.. I found that, while logging the info to a flat file it writes to multiple flat files, the moment it starts writing to multiple files the second thread stops without leaving any trace..

I use Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging for logging purpose.

Comment: Looks like deadlock has take place. Do you use any synchronization patterns inside your methods? Besides, I suppose, that your threads generate context switching most of their time... which isn't an effective way to manage threads.

Comment: It seems like your `Thread.Sleep()` wouldn't get called at all? Is this desired behavior?

Comment: Having an empty catch block isn't going to make diagnosing the issue any easier - if that's what your actual code looks like, of course nothing is logged - you're suppressing the errors before anything can notice them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The one which I mentioned is only the skeleton of the code .. RealTime I do handle & write exceptions to log file